# I need advice on storing application level encrypted data

Tags: mysql, security, full-text-search, encryption

I just want to ask, what is your solution on storing encrypted data on database? And also how you do searching on it?
For now the subject database server is mysql.

Disk level encryption is not an option. I also research about database level encryption but, MySql TDE is not for me, and also if you migrate to other database server in my understanding you need to re-encrypt all the data.

So my last bet is application level encryption. And I tried to implement it using AES-GCM, but on this I will lose database searching, because encrypting the same data with the same key and id will produce different results. Now I got an idea but, i don't know what would be the risk implementing it. I was thinking blind indexing.

What I am planning to do is to store 2 version of the encrypted data. first the data will be encrypted with aes-gcm, then store another version of it using one-way encryption on this same data will produce the same hash. So the first encryption is reversible but not searchable, while the second one is not reversible but I can do whole word searching.

The obvious drawback of this is speed. But I want also to ask if in security perspective is it feasible? And also how do you do a search query on encrypted database using the partial text of the data?

Thank you

Comment: Where is this application being presented? Is there any chance of the user being able to decompile the app and gain access to your encryption methods?

Comment: There is a part of the app that will reside on the tenant server. But all the keys needed to encrypt/decrypt the data will be requested online from the main server.